# Prefab / GameObject as Camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I allow the user to drag and drop a camera prefab in the inspector, but then when I try to use that in the following snippet, I get an error, which I understand why (a variable of type `Camera` is required in the method) but I cannot seem to find the right way of casting it as a camera.

I looked through the various available methods to see if there is a way of casting with `.` or using `as Camera` or `GetComponent<Camera>` but none of the variations I tried works.

When I google using these keywords *(unity cast prefab gameobject camera as camera)* I do not find a previous question on this. Could someone please help me understand how I can do this?

```
public GameObject myCamera;
planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(myCamera);
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you try `GetComponent<Camera>`?

Comment: When I try `GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(_renderCamera.GetComponent<Camera>)` I get `The best overloaded method match for UnityEngine.GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(UnityEngine.Camera) has some invalid arguments` and `Argument #1 cannot convert method group expression to type UnityEngine.Camera`

Comment: It should be `GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(_renderCamera.GetComp‌​onent<Camera>())`. Notice the `()` after `<Camera>` because that is a function.

Comment: @Programmer Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @Programmer What if there is **another script** attached to the **same object** in which I also want to access the camera? I did `initialDistanceToCamera = Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, GetComponent<Camera>().transform.position)` but I got `There is no Camera attached to the game object, but a script is trying to access it.` These two scripts are on the same object. The first script(in my post) accesses the camera in the scene by having a public field for drag&drop. How can I access the camera in the second script without having the same drag&drop public field?

Comment: That should work. If not then ask a new question that explains what is attached where. Maybe also with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
public Camera myCamera;
planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(myCamera);
```

or:

```
public GameObject myCamera;
planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(myCamera.GetComponent<Camera>());
```